# Highchart Click Event

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, highcharts

I am currently working on Highchart integration, where I have multiple series of data categorized by month,
Its some what similar to the output in this example,
[image]

When click on a particular point on the chart, I want to show all the series points data for that particular category in a new popup window,

assume in the example above, if i click over the Tokyo on February, i want to get all the other 3 cities data for February and show on a modal window or new pie chart,

Only i want to know how to get all intersecting series data? can anyone give example on how to get this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to compare `x` value of each point:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function(){
                    var x = this.x;

                    Highcharts.each(this.series.chart.series, function(s){
                        Highcharts.each(s.points, function(p){
                            if (p.x === x) {
                                console.log(p);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9sg17vne/

Or in case with shared tooltip - get `hoverPoints`:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    console.log(this.series.chart.hoverPoints)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wo3r20nj/